# Difference of using the <NextLink/> and the <Button href="/somePage"/> in the Mui intuitive React UI tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I am working on a project and wanted to know if there is any significant difference in the use of these two components.

Previously, the return button was done like this:

```
      <NextLink
        href="/settings"
        passHref
      >
        <Button
          component="a"
          startIcon={<ArrowBackIcon fontSize="small" />}
        >
          Voltar
        </Button>
      </NextLink>
```

But thinking a little bit, would it be a problem to do it this way?

```
        <Button
        href="/settings"
        passHref
        component="a"
        startIcon={<ArrowBackIcon fontSize="small" />}
        >
            Voltar
        </Button>
```

Both used from the [Mui](https://mui.com/pt/) intuitive React UI tools. Do you think there is any significant difference between the two? If not, what is NextLink for?

I tried to shorten the code.

Comment: In terms of accessibility buttons shouldn't be used for navigation. They should only be used to trigger an update/change etc on the page. Anchors/links should be solely used for navigation.

Answer (score 1):

The NextLink component provides many more options in the href attribute. You can check it below: [next/link](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#with-url-object).

Comment: Your answer could be improved by giving at least one example code which can show difference. and/or adding some explanation rather than just link to component.